# Building GDAL with ECW SDK on Windows

Tags: gdal, windows, ecw, compile

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 to open and build the GDAL 1.10 source (using the "makegdal10.sln"). This builds without an issue.

Now I want to include the ECW support by including the ECW v5.0 SDK (downloaded from Intergraph). It is installed to "C:\Intergraph\ECWSDK" and the relevant nmake.opt now looks as follows:

```
ECWDIR  =  "C:\Intergraph\ECWSDK"
ECWFLAGS = -DECWSDK_VERSION=50 \
       -I$(ECWDIR)\include \
       -I$(ECWDIR)\include/NCSECW/api -I$(ECWDIR)\include/NCSECW/jp2 \
       -I$(ECWDIR)\include/NCSECW/ecw
ECWLIB  =  $(ECWDIR)\lib\vc90\win32\NCSEcw.lib
```

However when building I get the following errors and have no idea what it means:

```
Error   6   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   (file)gdal110.dll

Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::~basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >(void)" (__imp_??1?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall ECWDataset::WriteHeader(void)" (?WriteHeader@ECWDataset@@AAEXXZ)   (file)ecwdataset.obj


Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: wchar_t const * __thiscall std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> >::c_str(void)const " (__imp_?c_str@?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@QBEPB_WXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual enum CPLErr __thiscall ECWDataset::SetMetadataItem(char const *,char const *,char const *)" (?SetMetadataItem@ECWDataset@@UAE?AW4CPLErr@@PBD00@Z)   (file)gdal-1.10.1\ecwdataset.obj

Error   8   error MSB3073: The command "cd C:\Will\Mapserver\gdal-1.10.1\ && nmake -f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1500 DEBUG=1 && nmake -f makefile.vc MSVC_VER=1500 DEBUG=1 install" exited with code 2.  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.MakeFile.Target

Error   7   error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\bin\link.EXE"' : return code '0x460'  ...\gdal-1.10.1\NMAKE   makegdal
```

Comment: was your gdal compiled in debug and release mode ?

Comment: yes, compiling in release mode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved this issue by going through the make file and realizing it is configured for Visual Studio 2008.  I made the following changes to the nmake.opt file to get it to build successfully in 2010:

1. Changed the !IFNDEF MSVC_VER to default to 2010 (not sure this is absolutely necessary):

   !IFNDEF MSVC_VER
   MSVC_VER=1600

   !ENDIF
2. Pointing to the VC100 folder in the ECW config section since we're compiling on VS2010, this section now looks like this:

   ECWDIR  =  "C:\Intergraph\ECWSDK"

   ECWFLAGS = -DECWSDK_VERSION=50 \

   ```
      -I$(ECWDIR)\include \

      -I$(ECWDIR)\include/NCSECW/api -I$(ECWDIR)\include/NCSECW/jp2 \

      -I$(ECWDIR)\include/NCSECW/ecw
   ```

   ECWLIB  =  $(ECWDIR)\lib\vc100\win32\NCSEcw.lib

Feeling a bit silly, but it's my fist make file troubleshooting effort! 
Apologies, the formatting seems a bit screwy on the code block above.